# Selective combination of buildTypes and productFlavors

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Can I do that?

I have following setup:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        // ...

    }
    release {
        // ...
    }

productFlavors {
    flavorDimensions "buildType", "versionType"

    fastBuild {
        minSdkVersion 21
        dimension "buildType"
    }
    regular {
        minSdkVersion setup.minSdk
        dimension "buildType"
    }
    free {
        dimension "versionType"
    }
    pro {
        applicationIdSuffix ".premium"
        dimension "versionType"
    }
}
```

This combines to 8 build variants. Actually I only need following 3:

- fastBuildDebugPro (my test build)
- regularBuildFreeRelease
- regularBuildProRelease

Can I somehow exclude the other 5 auto generated build variants?